# Localization doesn't work in fragments if setRetainInstance(true)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

For fragments if setRetainInstance(true) On changing the language from settings and coming back to application localization is not working, If we don't set setRetainInstance(true) App is crashing stating objects inside fragments null. How do we handle localization changes for activity with multiple fragments?

Comment: on localization change the activity has to be recreated to take changes. Fragment has to be recreated as well. But the problem in your case is that if using `setRetainInstance(true)`, the fragment is not recreated. So you probably have to manually change all strings, etc.

Comment: Thanks @VladyslavMatviienko for the answer.